# AWK substract different fields in different rows if consecutive fields are identical

Tags: awk, field

I have a file looking like this:

```
19  51261707    51261802    MSTRG.10026.3   -
19  51261823    51261997    MSTRG.10026.3   -
19  51262046    51262097    MSTRG.10026.3   -
1   149551909   149556187   MSTRG.1004.1    -
1   149559605   149559936   MSTRG.1004.1    -
19  52829322    52829588    MSTRG.10054.1   +
19  52840151    52840785    MSTRG.10054.1   +
1   148371653   148371859   MSTRG.1007.1    -
1   148407140   148407240   MSTRG.1007.1    -
19  54029553    54029789    MSTRG.10088.1   -
19  54035061    54035106    MSTRG.10088.1   -
```

I want to merge the consecutive lines that have $4 field identical. So the result would be like

```
19  51261707    51261802    MSTRG.10026.3   -  19   51261823    51261997    MSTRG.10026.3   -
19  51261823    51261997    MSTRG.10026.3   -  19   51262046    51262097    MSTRG.10026.3   -
1   149551909   149556187   MSTRG.1004.1    -  1    149559605   149559936   MSTRG.1004.1    -
19  52829322    52829588    MSTRG.10054.1   +  19   52840151    52840785    MSTRG.10054.1   +
1   148371653   148371859   MSTRG.1007.1    -  1    148407140   148407240   MSTRG.1007.1    -
```

and so on.

So when the $4 field repeats 3 times, I obtain two combinations, say, n-1 combinations where n is the number of times $4 appears.

AWK solution or Perl would help

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: I did this by copying the two files and pasting them removing the first line of the second and then removing all lines with $4 != $9, but this was a kind of manual approach. It would be fine to get a nice awk line.

Comment: What's the output when there's just 1 line with a given $4 value? SKip it or duplicate it or leave it as 1 or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test example you present, the following will work

```
$ awk '(t==$4){print r,$0}{r=$0;t=$4}' file
```

This will only work if `$4` **never** appears a single time!

If you want to have this corrected, you need to fix it a bit.

```
$ awk '(t2!=t1 && t1!=$4){print r}(t1==$4){print r,$0}
       {r=$0;t2=t1;t1=$4}END{if(t2!=$4) print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if($4==pc){c+=1; print pl, $0}else{if(c==0 && NR!=1){print pl}; c=0}; pl=$0; pc=$4}END{if(!c)print pl}' file
```

Output :

```
19  51261707    51261802    MSTRG.10026.3   - 19  51261823    51261997    MSTRG.10026.3   -
19  51261823    51261997    MSTRG.10026.3   - 19  51262046    51262097    MSTRG.10026.3   -
1   149551909   149556187   MSTRG.1004.1    - 1   149559605   149559936   MSTRG.1004.1    -
19  52829322    52829588    MSTRG.10054.1   + 19  52840151    52840785    MSTRG.10054.1   +
1   148371653   148371859   MSTRG.1007.1    - 1   148407140   148407240   MSTRG.1007.1    -
19  54029553    54029789    MSTRG.10088.1   - 19  54035061    54035106    MSTRG.10088.1   -
```